# Why doesn't the Password Recovery link show up in my Login control?

Tags: authentication, asp.net-membership

I have an ASP.NEt 2010 web app. I have a login control with the following definition. However, not matter what I do, the "Forgot Your Password" link is not display?

```
<asp:Login ID="LoginUser" runat="server" 
EnableViewState="false" 
RenderOuterTable="false" 
PasswordRecoveryUrl="~/Account/RecoverPassword.aspx" 
PasswordRecoveryText="Forgot Your Password?">
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your password recovery settings for the `membershipelement` in the web.config.  What are the values for `enablePasswordRetrieval` and `enablePasswordReset`?